# Git will not stage a tracked file

Tags: git

Git isn't staging a tracked file, even when I ask it firmly.  I have a web.config file with changes.  `git status` shows it as modified and unstaged.  Then I say `git add web.config`. It doesn't complain, but another `git status` still shows it as modified and unstaged.  It works fine on other files.

So somehow I've goofed up the local state of this file.  How can I reset that, if possible without losing the changes?

Comment: Does `git add -v web.config` report anything?

Comment: What about `git add -u`?

Comment: `git add -u web.config` also says nothing.  The file is still unstaged.

Comment: Well I meant just `git add -u` alone, but I don't think adding `web.config` as an argument is going to change its meaning.

Comment: Aha!  `git add -u` staged it, and all other tracked files.  If you write this as an answer, I'll accept.  (After reading the man page, I'm not sure why this worked.)

Comment: Make sure the file hasn't an extra space to its name.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out.  I'm using Git bash on Windows.  I'm relying on filename completion from the shell.  The file's name is `Web.config`.  I had been typing `git add web.c` and pressing TAB.  It would complete the filename, keeping the lowercase `w`.  Git wouldn't complain, but wouldn't stage the file.  Using uppercase `W` and filename completion works.